# Python split string on delimiter but not on a certain variation of such delimiter

Tags: python, regex, split, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

I want to split a long string in Python based on the delimiter '--', but not split if the '--' is immediately proceeded by 'fail'. Then put the removed delimiter, '--', back on resulting strings in the split array. Below is an example.

I want:

```
"--conf example1 --conf curl --fail exception --env example2"
```

After the split, become:

```
["--conf example1", "--conf curl --fail exception", "--env example2"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of *postive* lookahead and *negative* lookahead:

```
\s+(?=--)(?!--fail)
```

We here thus split with spacing characters with a positive lookahead to look for double dashes, and negative lookahead to ignore `--fail`:

```
>>> re.split(r'\s+(?=--)(?!--fail)', "--conf example1 --conf curl --fail exception --env example2")
['--conf example1', '--conf curl --fail exception', '--env example2']
```

Note that here `--fail-foo` will not be splitted as well. You can however add a spacing character to the negative lookahead:

```
\s+(?=--)(?!--fail\s)
```